# MS-Access between filter on form

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter, between

Hi there I've created a form on access which looks like this: [image: http://imgur.com/XS0vE08]

I can make it so, that all the filters work, except for the Year and Length filters.
The Year boxes are unbound, and the left is called **Year1** and the right one is **Year2**. I've tried to use **Me.Filter** code, but it doesn't work. It doesn't come up with an error, it just won't filter my data. So what I need is to make it so that the user can enter a year in **Year1** and in **Year2**, and it filters the data between those two years. So for example they put 2000 in **Year1** and 2010 in **Year2**, and then when they run the query it only shows data from 2000 to 2010.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
 Private Sub Year2_AfterUpdate()
 Me.Filter = "[Year] BETWEEN #" & Me.Year1 & "# AND #" &  Me.Year2 & "#"
 Me.Filteron = true
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)
(If you could explain what code does what that would be much appreciated too, so that I can learn to write it myself, and so that I can understand better! Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

You only use the **"#"** characters when you are using a date literal in your filter.  If it is just a numeric you would use:

```
 Me.Filter = "[Year] BETWEEN " & Me.Year1 & " AND " &  Me.Year2
```

If [Year] actually IS a date then you should use:

```
 Me.Filter = "[Year] BETWEEN #01/01/" & Me.Year1 & "# AND #12/31/" &  Me.Year2 & "#"
```

Which will evaluate to `[Year] BETWEEN #01/01/2010# AND #12/31/2011#` if you enter 2010 and 2011 in the year textboxes.

Comment: [Year] is my column in which all my data  is which contains my years is in. I changed the code an took out the **"#"** but it still won't work! Argh! I've tried a million things with this and I don't understand why it's not working! :( Is there anything else I should have put in place for it to work?

Comment: It should work.  What type is your [Year] column?  Are you changing the value of Year2 to test (because your filter is only getting set in the Year2_AfterUpdate() event as far as you've shown us.  Can you show the code of your command button?

Comment: Type? It's just a column with years all down it. General? Maybe? No I haven't changed the value of Year2 to test, how can I do that? Sorry, I'm kind of new to Excel. And my RunQuery button is just a macro set to Open Query

Comment: The query is querying a table, I'm talking about the type of [Year] in the table you are querying.  Right click on table, click on design, look for [Year], see what it says in the properties.  Also this is an Access question, right, not Excel?

Comment: Ah. The type is a number. Yea sorry, it's Access (i was just tired so I wrote excel).
Should I change the number to Date/Time? Although in general I don't think it should matter, because all I have is e.g. 1996, 2001, etc, so I only need to search between two numbers. Why won't this work! D:

Comment: It should work with the first filter I showed (without the #'s) Put a debug.print "[Year] BETWEEN " & Me.Year1 & " AND " &  Me.Year2 in your code and see if you see anything strange in the immediate window of the vba editor.

Comment: Ok I put in the Debug.Print, and nothing came up. It just did the usual - showed me the whole database, unfiltered...

Comment: The results appear in the immediate window of the VBA Editor

Comment: Ok I've figured if I typed something in, then remove, then click somewhere else it gives me a run-time error 3075. 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Year BETWEEN 2000 AND'

Answer (score 0):

You must use the name of the query (frmAufträgeQuery) and NOT the Form (frmAufträge):

On Error Resume Next

FromDate = "01.01.2021"

ToDate = "01.04.2021"

Me.Filter = "([frmAufträgeQuery].[Administrativ abgeschlossen] Between #" & Format(FromDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND #" & Format(ToDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#)"

Me.FilterOn = True